# Java 6 Annotations Repeating with or without parameter

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have the following annotation:

```
public @interface ExcludeVariable {
    String list();
}
```

I want to be able preprocessing this in two different ways

First:

```
@ExcludeVariable // without parameter
int a;
```

Second:

```
@ExcludeVariable(list="a,b") // with parameter
public void test(){
     int a;
     int b;
     int c;
}
```

In Java 8 there is an option to "repeat" annotations

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html

How to handle this in Java 6

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "default". Read more [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/UsingDefaultValues.htm)

```
public @interface ExcludeVariable {
    String list() default "";
}
```